# Fetch specific data from Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I want to check if the specific number exists in database so it will fetch the password corresponding to the number or else it will return number does not exist in database in Flutter.

[image]

```
var dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("NewUsers");
dbRef.equalTo(numberController.text).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
  if(snapshot.value.isNotEmpty){
    var dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    dbRef.child(numberController.text).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
      snapshot.value.forEach((key,values) {
        print(values["Password"]);
      });
    });
  }
  else{
    print("pleasesignup first");
  }
});
```

After this I'm getting the error `Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isNotEmpty' was called on null`

Comment: for What specific number you want to check existence of?

Comment: The number above the first unique key which starts with 9971*******. I've to fetch one value at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("newUsers");
dbRef.orderByKey().equalTo(numberController.text).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
     if(snapshot.value.isNotEmpty){
         var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference("newUsers");
           ref.child(numberController.text).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
                print(snapshot.value); 
                snapshot.value.forEach((key,values) {
                   print(values["Password"]);
              });
          });
       }
   });
```

First add a reference to the `newUsers` and using the query `orderByKey().equalTo(numberController.text)` and then by doing `snapshot.value.isNotEmpty` it will check if key exists in the database, if it does retrieve the `password`.

Comment: I'm getting this error ** Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isNotEmpty' was called on null.**

Comment: That error means you called the method on a null value - so check if your ```snapshot.value``` is returning null

Comment: your code is different than what I provided.. what is `newUsers`? There is no `child("NewUsers")` node in your database

Comment: Actually the number whose existence I'm looking for is the child of NewUsers.

Comment: I represented the number with black "No" in the image.

Comment: is not `newUsers` above the "no" number?

Comment: Yes, newUsers is above the number.

Comment: And newUsers contains lot of numbers. So I want to check the existence of number provided by user and if the number exists in database it will fetch the corresponding password.

Comment: @PraveenGupta in you code you should do `dbRef.orderByKey().equalTo(numberController.text).once().then((DataSnapshot`

Comment: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.Tried calling: []("Password")

Comment: E/flutter (28868): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on null.
E/flutter (28868): Receiver: null
E/flutter (28868): Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (dynamic, dynamic) => Null)

Comment: Hey @PeterHaddad, this edited code worked for me. Thank You so much. It just need a small change you cannot directly provide reference in instance.reference("Here").So we need to add child of it and then provide the reference.

Comment: Hey @PeterHaddad , One more problem when the provided number does not exists in database ,it will not move to the else part instead it throws an error saying "The getter 'isNotEmpty' was called on null."

Comment: before `if(snapshot.value.isNotEmpty){` check `if(snapshot.value !=null)`

Comment: Hey @PeterHaddad, the above code fetch the password two times and one time it shows null and other time it fetch the correct one. How should I resolve this.

Comment: @PraveenGupta please ask a different question, Im sure u are getting this null first because the data is still not retrieved.. the API is asynchronous https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean, please ask a different question with more details and write the code where u are using the result of `once()`

Comment: @PeterHaddad I got the null value second times. Even I asked one different question separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("newUsers");
dbRef.orderByKey().equalTo(numberController.text).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
     if(snapshot && snapshot.value){
         var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference("newUsers");
         ref.child(numberController.text).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
           print(snapshot.value); 
           snapshot.value.forEach((key,values) {
             print(values["Password"]);
          });
        });
     }
     else{
       print("No Record Found");
     }
 });
```

Comment: I'm getting error on if condition of snapshot, it says the operand of && operation must be assigned to bool.

Comment: Even I cannot directly pass the reference in instance.reference(" ").it says 0 positional argument expected and found one so I tried by providing reference in its child, but didn't work.